# How to set exact position of a guide line in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

How to set exact position of a guide line in Illustrator?

I read I can select guide but I can't. Even if I select guideline in Layers pane, I can't edit it's coordinates.

Answer (score 5):

To select.

1. Make sure the layer the guides are on is not locked.
2. Make sure the menu item **View → Guides → Lock Guides** is not active.

Once selected then you can type in the position of the guide in the control panel or using transform panel, just like for everything else. Or enable grid snap prior to generation, again just like for everything else.

Also, FYI layers highlighting a item in layers panel does not select a item. It activates the layer the object is in for adding new objects (yeah weird). You need to click on the spherical balloon next to the item to select a object. But no you can not select locked objects form the layer palette.